# How to iterate through HashMap in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap, hashtable

[my code loook at the out put](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3and4.png)

i want to iterate through the has map in java. i am not able to get the keys from my code. it gives me random kind of keys that's not what i want. my keys are of class type.

i have tried many things but i don't know exactly how can i get the keys . i can get the keys when i have the keys of primitive or wrapper classes type but not when i am entering a key from user defined class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I print my Java object without getting "SomeType@2f92e0f4"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4)

Comment: The code already gets your keys, you simply don't know how to print them properly.

Comment: 'random kind of keys' is actually the combination of class name & hashcode of the objects t1, t2 ,etc.

Comment: In the future, please don't post pictures of your code and output, but post them as text instead. It's much easier to answer in that case.

Answer (score 0):

> Iterating through HashMap in Java printing all keys and values together:

```java
    map.forEach((key, value) -> {
            System.out.println(key + " " + value);
        });
```

**Note:** we are using the `forEach` lambda expression, which needs Java 8, but it is very clear & concise.

Comment: This is not at all related to OP's question.